# Get UTM coordinate from mouse click in ArcMap using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcobjects, coordinate-system, c#

I am using ArcObjects C# tool in ArcGIS that identifies map coordinates when a user clicks on a location within a map. Here's the code that I have used:

```
 protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs arg)
    {
        Fr1.Show();

        IMxDocument pMxDoc =(IMxDocument)ArcMap.Application.Document;
        IPoint pPoint = pMxDoc.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint(arg.X, arg.Y);
        MessageBox.Show("Map X: " + pPoint.X + "\nMap Y: " + pPoint.Y);
    }
```

My map use units of Meters so the tool displays the Meters coordinates. How can I have this tool return UTM ?

Comment: By UTM, do you mean MGRS or USNG or aother alphanumeric version? For instance, 11SAB23445678 or 11S 345678 4349584?

Comment: i mean WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_32N

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your IPoint reference then use the **Project** method to project it to whatever coordinate system you like.

[IGeometry.Project help from Esri](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IGeometry_Project.htm)

Here's a code example:

```
Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriGeometry.SpatialReferenceEnvironment");
System.Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
ISpatialReferenceFactory spatialRefFactory= obj as ISpatialReferenceFactory;
ISpatialReference spatialReference = spatialRefFactory.CreateProjectedCoordinateSystem(<ZoneNumber>);
pPoint.Project(spatialReference);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your question since UTM is also meters, but the easiest way to change from your current coordinate system to another is to project it.

```
//get your desired spatial reference
ISpatialReferenceFactory3 spatialReferenceFactory = new SpatialReferenceEnvironment() as ISpatialReferenceFactory3;
ISpatialReference spatialReference = spatialReferenceFactory.CreateSpatialReference((int)esriSRProjCSType.esriSRProjCS_WGS1984UTM_54N); 
pPoint.Project(spatialReference);
```

In this case it will project to UTM 54N (1984). You can switch that out in the CreateSpatialReference parameter with any of the enumerations in:

- esriSRProjCSType
- esriSRProjCS2Type
- esriSRProjCS3Type
- esriSRProjCS4Type

There are also:

- esriSRGeoCSType
- esriSRGeoCS2Type
- esriSRGeoCS3Type

if you want to go to a geographic coordinate system.

The pPoint.Project() method depends on pPoint already having a SpatialReference assigned to it. I'm not sure if the ToMapPoint() method returns a point with a SpatialReference. If pPoint doesn't have one simply assign it using the

`pPoint.SpatialReference = pMxDoc.FocusMap.SpatialReference;`